# Cancel Selector in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have scenario that in which i am using selector in TableViewCell as bellow and when I click on back button in my view I want to cancel that selector and I am sending dictionary as object in Selector

My code is as bellow

**In Header File**

```
 NSMutableDictionary* photoDict;
 NSMutableDictionary* dictImages;
```

**In .M file**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MyCellNib" owner:self options:Nil];
        cell = detailChainObj;
    }

    NSString* avatarURL =@"image_Url"; //Any url of image for cell.
    NSString *key =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Key%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    dictImages = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:imageViewCell,@"Img",imgURL,@"imgURL",key,@"key", nil];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(DownloadLinkzImageOfUser:) withObject:dictImages];


    if([photoDic valueForKey:keyAvt])
    {
        NSData* data = (NSData*)[photoDic valueForKey:key];
        imageViewCell.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(DownloadImagesForCell:) withObject:dictImages];
    }
}


//

-(void)DownloadImagesForCell:(NSDictionary *)result
{
    UIImageView* img = (UIImageView*)[result objectForKey:@"Img"];
    NSString* urlAvt = [result valueForKey:@"imgURL"];
    if([urlAvt isEqualToString:@"No Image"])
    {
       img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noimg.png"];
    }
    else
    {
       NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]];
       img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
       [photoDic setValue:data forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result valueForKey:@"key"]]];
    }
 }
```

Now I want to cancel this selecter when I press back button

and please keep in mind that I have already use

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(DownloadImagesForCell:) object:dictImages];
```

Comment: even after using cancel request is you selector gets called.?

Comment: ya I think problem with Object which I pass with cancel Selector method.

Comment: `DownloadImagesForCell` works on a different thread from the main UI thread, right? If you've called `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget` from the main thread, then I don't think it'll work...

Comment: try using  `+ (void)cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)aTarget`which will cancel all perform requests to this target.. use only if you are not using other perform selectors in this class.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I guess this method works for  performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: only.